# regex любая последовательность нужных слов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, faq

Помогите составить regex который найдет текст в котором есть business, pay и rent в любой последовательности.
а то у меня только получилось сделать в одной (и то, наверное можно было проще) =((

```
(pay).*?(rent).*?(business)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка с пустым вхождением:

```
^(?=.*\bbusiness\b)(?=.*\bmake\b)(?=.*\bpay\b)(?=.*\brent\b)
```

Проверка, выбирающая всю строку:

```
^(?=.*\bbusiness\b)(?=.*\bmake\b)(?=.*\bpay\b)(?=.*\brent\b).*$
```

В обоих случаях используются `\b` для проверки на целые слова.

Сниппет для проверки (с кириллицей не работает `\b` - это недостаток js, не регулярки):

```css
input { border: 1px solid; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^(?=.*\bbusiness\b)(?=.*\bmake\b)(?=.*\bpay\b)(?=.*\brent\b).*$" autofocus value="make business to pay your rent">
```